# Sorting an array of String in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

I need to sort an array of `String` like the following, in ascending order.

```java
String str[] = {"ASE", "LSM", "BSE", "LKCSE", "DFM"};
```

How to do that? I need help.

Comment: did you try using [net.rim.device.api.util.Arrays.sort(Object[] a, Comparator c)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/3.7api/net/rim/device/api/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[], net.rim.device.api.util.Comparator)) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is based on [Signare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/896391/) and [HeartBeat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/952526/)'s suggestion. Explore this [link](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/3.7api/net/rim/device/api/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20net.rim.device.api.util.Comparator%29) for details. Also this link, [Sorting using java.util.Array](http://www.drbob42.com/jbuilder/jbjar058.htm) might be helpful.

```java
// Initialization of String array 
String strs[] = {"One", "Two", "Threee", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven"};

// implementation of Comparator
Comparator strComparator = new Comparator() {
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        return o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString());
    }
};

// Sort
Arrays.sort(strs, strComparator);
```

Comment: This is the easiest and best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TestSort1 {

String [] words = { "Réal", "Real", "Raoul", "Rico" };

 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    try {
  Writer w = getWriter();
  w.write("Before :\n");

  for (String s : words) {
    w.write(s + " ");
  }

  java.util.Arrays.sort(words);

  w.write("\nAfter :\n");
  for (String s : words) {
    w.write(s + " ");
  }
  w.flush();
  w.close();
}
catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}

 }

// useful to output accentued characters to the console
  public static Writer getWriter() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    if (System.console() == null) {
      Writer w =
        new BufferedWriter
         (new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, "Cp850"));
      return w;
    }
    else {
      return System.console().writer();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can i use "java.util.Arrays.sort(words)" in blackberry?

Comment: Here are the [package javadocs for java.util][1] from the Blackberry JDE site. There is no Arrays class http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/java/util/package-frame.html

Comment: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/3.7api/net/rim/device/api/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:-

```
String str[]={"ASE","LSM","BSE","LKCSE","DFM"};

for(int j = 0; j < str.length; j++){
               for(int i = j + 1; i < str.length; i++) {
                   if(str[i].compareTo(str[j]) < 0) {
                       String t = str[j];
                       str[j] = str[i];
                       str[i] = t;
                   }
               }

    }
```